# POPClient missing reference

Tags: c#

```
private POPClient popClient=new POPClient();
```

When I write this I got an Error;

> The type or namespace name 'POPClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I do not know what type or reference I need to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you trying to use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125689/PopClient-A-POP3-companion-to-SmtpClient ?

Comment: Did you add the .dll containing POPClient as a reference to the project?